# Can you get your girlfriend back after being dumped?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

In GTA: San Andreas, you are able to date several of the female NPCs in the game.  However, if you have enough bad dates or if you neglect them, your relationship meter drops to 0% and you are eventually dumped.  Are you able to recover the relationship and get the benefits of having girlfriend back?

Comment: Today in Question Titles on Gaming.StackExchange.com.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic bec-- wait, no, nevermind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Curiously enough it comes down to a collectible. Usually when they dump you you cannot date them again, however, if you have [collected all the oysters](http://gta.wikia.com/Oysters), the 50 of them, that will allow you to date them again:

> Collecting all fifty is required for 100% Completion and the rewards for this are $100 for every single oyster found, Carl's lung capacity increases to maximum and his girlfriends react as if he always has full sex appeal.... [snip]
>   In addition, if a girlfriend dumps you during the game, **collecting all fifty oysters will allow you to date her again**, whereas normally this is not possible.

They can be re-found in their original spawn locations.

Comment: do they come back if you kill them? with the girlfriend you have to date to help with the Casino heist one of the easier ways to get the card (aside from wearing the gimp suit) is to take her on a date and shoot her

Comment: @Memor-X - No, once your girlfriend is killed they do not respawn.